# Javascript onChange dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call a javascript function onChange of an HTML Select.

HTML Doc:

```
<select name="network" onChange="test(this)">
    <option value="net1">Net1</option>
    <option value="net2">net2</option>
</select>
<script>
    alert("test");
    var URLArray = [];
    function test(str){
        alert("test");
    }
</script>
```

I get the first alert, but not the second one. What am I missing?

EDIT: The code actually works, but for whatever reason, I cannot use the separate panes in JSFiddle. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PT38t/

Comment: I was using JSFiddle as well, but I had them in the separate boxes. I guess that doesn't work right?

Comment: I think this is jsFiddle's way of telling you not to use global functions ;-) jsFiddle hasn't placed your function test on "window"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When jsFiddle runs your code, it wraps it in a closure like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
    alert("test");
    var URLArray = [];
    function test(str){
        alert("test");
    }
}//]]>  
</script>
```

So the function you defined "test", is never available as a global function, therefore not accessible by the inline javascript which you placed on the select tag.

I strongly suggest you learn to use jQuery instead to attach your event handlers like this:

```
<select name="network">
    <option value="net1">Net1</option>
    <option value="net2">net2</option>
</select>

$(function () {
    console.log("oh look, the document is ready");

    $("[name=network]").change(function () {
        console.log("now my code is groovy, but i might want to use an id rather than name selector"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Is jQuery standard, or will I have to install extra stuff? (sorry for such a basic question, I am very new at web dev).

Comment: @Jeff It's a javascript library that's pretty much used by everyone doing web development these days. http://jquery.com/. you don't have to use it, there are pure javascript solutions, but it makes life a whole lot easier if you do :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll see about using that!

Answer (score 0):

Your script is Ok, you just put the same value ("test") for both `alert`.

```
<script>
    alert("test1");
    var URLArray = [];
    function test(str){
        alert("test2");
    }
</script>
```

Or maybe the final goal is this...

```
function test(elm){
    alert(elm.value);
}
```

Comment: That is fine, it would just print "test" twice." My code actually works, I think using the separate panes in JSFiddle is what killed me.

Answer (score 0):

try to move your script above your first call like below:

```
<script>
    alert("test");
    var URLArray = [];
    function test(str){
        alert("test");
    }
</script>


<select name="network" onChange="test(this)">
    <option value="net1">Net1</option>
    <option value="net2">net2</option>
</select>
```

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akTfM/) as you see I set the javascript to be put in the header.

Answer (score 0):

As Panayot said, your code is OK, but I'd rather use `console.log()` instead of `alert`. It's much easier to view on the console than following alerts.

```
<select name="network" onChange="test(this)">
    <option value="net1">Net1</option>
    <option value="net2">net2</option>
</select>
<script>
    console.log("test1")
    var URLArray = [];
    function test(str){
        console.log("test2");
    }
</script>
```